# Change the Default Option in a Select Listbox an hide show elements

Tags: jquery

```
 <select name="cart" id="cart">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">visa</option>
    <option value="2">master</option>
    <option value="3">american</option>
 </select>
```

I want to be if visa selected my div #parent1 is show other divs are hide.
my jquery code

```
           $("#parent1,#parent2,#parent3").css("display","none"); 
           $("select").change(function() {
                if ($("select").val() == "1") {
                    $("#parent1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect   
                    //$("#parent2,#parent3").css("display","none");

                 }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$("#parent1,#parent2,#parent3").css("display","none"); 
$("select").change(function() {
    $("div[id^='parent']").hide();
    $("div[id='parent"+$(this).val()+"']").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

1. add a class ".cart-details" to your '#parent' elements so you can target them all at once. You can then also hide them all via css on init.
2. on change, hide them all and show the correct one with `$("#parent" + this.value)`
3. trigger the change event after binding so you get your initial setting

Markup:

*Note: I have changed the IDs to "card1, card2..." because it is clearer but any ID will be ok*

```
<select name="cart" id="cart">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">visa</option>
    <option value="2">master</option>
    <option value="3">american</option>
 </select>
<div class="cart-details" id="cart1">Visa</div>
<div class="cart-details" id="cart2">Mastercard</div>
<div class="cart-details" id="cart3">American</div>​
```

Here's the code:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    // get the selected value
    var val = this.value;
    // hide all cart detail div
    $('.cart-details').hide();
    // show the one corresponding to the selected item
    $("#cart" + val).slideDown("fast");
})
// trigger the change event so the initial value is taken into account
.change();​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ZwtwP/)**